# How to validate the auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Iam using an auto complete to display the states and while clicking on any one of autocomplete then the relevant state id will be given to a hidden text field like

```
<input type="text" name="state_auto" id="state_auto">
<input type="hidden" name="iStateId" id="iStateId">
```

And it is working as per the need but while it coming to validation,Iam checking for iStateId like

```
iStateId: {
       required: true
},
```

But the validation is not working,I need to check for the id only not the text they are in the `state_auto` .and other fields are giving the error messages.Can anyone suggest me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ignore: [],
iStateId: {
       required: true
},
```

this will validate hidden field also